# Error Maven with mvn test

Tags: maven, build, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am using this tool for first time, and I can't build  a project correctly.

when i try the life cycle commands it builds succesfully with clean validate and compile. but when i try mvn test, it gives me this error :

```
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
---
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
---
[INFO] Total time: 4.410 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-25T11:33:07+02:00
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
---
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire- 
plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) on project gdp: Execution default-test of 
goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test failed. 
:NullPointerException
-> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e 
switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please 
read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
 http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

mvn -v 3.5.3
i am using a proxy and i did configure settings.xml file
Please help.
thank you

Comment: Are you using JDK 10 ? If so you have to upgrade to 2.21.0...

Comment: Please tell me how to do so ?

Comment: Are you using JDK 10 ?

Comment: yes i use jdk 10 ! i changed my maven version to 2.2.1 as you told me but it asks my to change to 3.0 or above because of the the project i am cloning

Comment: No didn't told you to change Maven version you should change the version of maven-surefire-plugin to 2.21.0 ...See my answer

Answer (score 5):

Change the version of maven-surefire-plugin via:

```
<project>
  .
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.21.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Where? in the pom file?

Comment: No i get this error in eclipse when i import an existing maven project :Description Resource Path Location Type
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:3.1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:3.1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out pom.xml /gdp line 1 Maven Configuration Problem

Comment: Yes you should change in the pom or better add this snippet to your pom file.

Comment: yes its a proxy issue.  in the settings.xml file, i did  uncomment the block proxy and add the host, port but nothing changed.